# What do you think of Paul Sheriff's Inner Circle?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have not been able to find any reviews or opinions on this site.  I did read his e-book "Fundamentals of N Tier" which I thought was very good.  Has anyone here joined the site? and if so what do you think of it?

Thanks

Comment: this is a very localized question as it will only appeal to those who have heard of Paul Sheriff's Inner Circle.

Comment: @rock: All the more reason to leave it.

Comment: Further, it is COMPLETELY off topic.

Answer (score 3):

I think he's charging money for something not very different from what you get here.  I also think his site intentionally makes it difficult to determine how *much* money he's charging.  Therefore, I have no interest whatsoever in joining.

Comment: Ok, with a *lot* of scrolling, I found the price: $500 or $1000, depending on which package you want.  I'm going to pass, thanks.